# Getting "Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes." when trying to redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes, config, ruby-on-rails-5

I’m using Rails 5.  I have this in my config/routes.rb file so that I can redirect a user to their dashboard if they are already logged in and they visit the root URL …

```
get '/dashboard' => 'users#show', as: :dashboard

root :to => "/dashboard", constraints: lambda { |user| user.user_signed_in? }
```

However, I’m getting an error, “Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes.” on the line

```
root :to => "/dashboard", constraints: lambda { |user| user.user_signed_in? }
```

Why isn’t “/dashboard” getting recognized and how can I correct the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your root path should be defined as: `root to: 'users#show'`. You need to specify the controller#action when using the `to` helper.

Alternatively, you could do `get 'dashboard', as: :root` but that would point to `dashboard#index`.

Comment: Is that the only way?  I would prefer to put a URL because the underlying controller-action pointed to by the URL might change, and thus I woudl only have to alter things in one place.

Comment: I don't think what you're looking for is possible. See my edit, but it wouldn't point to `users#show`.

Comment: Interesting.  Ok if its not possible I'll come back and accept but I'm going to do some digging around first just because it seems like I wouldn't be the first person to request something liek this.